# @IBOutletで関連付けられているのにnilになる

Tags: swift

XCode7.3(swift)でプログラムをしています。
UITableviewでリスト表示がうまくいっていたのですが、UINavigationControllerなどと変更を加えたり削除していたりしたら、ある時突然@IBOutletで関連付けられているにも関わらず

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

のエラーになる状況が発生しました。
該当リストは以下の通りです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この38行目で、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

という状況で、エラーになります。もちろんUITableViewに関連付けはされています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

何が原因で@IBOutletで関連付けされているにも関わらずnilになる現象が発生したのでしょうか？
補足ですがStoryboardの該当Viewのclassは本classになっています。

解決方法をご存知の方、ご教授お願いします。

Comment: 関連付けを行った後でソースコードを修正すると、時折そのような症状に出くわすことがあります。私の場合は、全部の接続を一旦削除して再度接続しなおすことで回復できたのですが、(ソースコードだけ流用して)新しいプロジェクトを作り直す必要があったと言う方もいます。とりあえず、「全部の接続を一旦削除して再度接続しなおす」を試してみてください。

Comment: 「一旦全て削除して再度接続しなおす」ですね。試してみます。

Comment: `NSCoder`を引数に持つ指定イニシャライザはありますか？

Comment: ありませんが、もしあったら本事象が発生するのでしょうか？